# WCF Data Services & EF 4.1 RC Code First - Overrode CreateDataSource, now how to use CurrentDataSource?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, odata, wcf-data-services, ef-code-first

I'm creating a WCF Data Services (OData) with EF 4.1 RC Code First. I've overrode the CreateDataSource method to make it work, but then I can't create operations that return an IQueryable or using `CurrentDataSource`. Is there a way to map CurrentDataSource property back to DbContext?

Here's my code:

```
protected override ObjectContext CreateDataSource()
{
    var context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)new NotesnhacContext()).ObjectContext;
    context.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

    return context;
}

[WebGet]
public IQueryable<MusicSheet> GetMusicSheets(int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{
    // This doesn't work... I can't access "MusicSheets"
    //return CurrentDataSource.MusicSheets.Where(... ... );
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the new CTP of WCF Data Services - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2011/03/09/announcing-wcf-data-services-march-2011-ctp2-for-net4-amp-sl4.aspx

With this CTP, one no longer needs to override the CreateDataSource method, and the CurrentDataSource is an instance of DBContext.

In other words, DbContext is fully supported in this CTP.

Hope this helps.

Thanks
Pratik

Comment: Pratik, I've updated my project to use the CPT2, everything seems to work fine except for my custom IQueryable method. This WCF Data Services is hosted within an asp.net mvc 3 app, I have configured my Global.ascx to ignore routes to the service folder. As you can see from my original code where I have the "GetMusicSheets" method, each time I go to this url, i.e. http://localhost/site/services/service.svc/GetMusicSheet?pageIndex=0&pageSize=5, I got a broken link message from the browser. Any idea why? Thanks a lot.

Comment: My bad :) I need to add my service operation to the DataServiceConfiguration... Thanks!